# Unknown name "update_sheet_properties"

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I am using the google-client-api-python v4 and trying to update the properties of a sheet using the following code

```
for sheet in result.get('sheets', ''):
    sheetId = (sheet.get("properties", {}).get("sheetId", 0))

    batch_request = {
      "requests": [
          {
              "UpdateSheetProperties": {
                  "properties": {
                      "sheetId": sheetId,
                      "gridProperties": {
                          "rowCount": 2000,
                          "columnCount": 4,
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      ],
    }
    result = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=batch_request).execute()
```

When I run the script I get the following error

> json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name
>   "update_sheet_properties" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field."

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I found the mistake

firstly this should have been

```
"updateSheetProperties": {
```

instead of

```
"UpdateSheetProperties": {
```

Also I needed to have the following line

```
"fields" : "gridProperties(rowCount, columnCount)"
```

The actual code would be

```
 for sheet in result.get('sheets', ''):
        sheetId = (sheet.get("properties", {}).get("sheetId", 0))

        batch_request = {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "updateSheetProperties": {
                        "properties": {
                            "sheetId": sheetId,
                            "gridProperties": {
                                "rowCount": 2000,
                                "columnCount": 4,
                            }
                        },
                        "fields" : "gridProperties(rowCount, columnCount)"
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
        result = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, body=batch_request).execute()
```

Jay