# "At least one field must be listed" Google Sheets API Move Sheet Error

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

Based on this answer:

[Move a sheet to a particular position using Python & the Google Sheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004124/move-a-sheet-to-a-particular-position-using-python-the-google-sheets-api)

I wrote this piece of code:

```
body = {'requests': [
    {'updateSheetProperties': {
        'properties': {
            'sheetId': sheetId,
            'index': 1
        }
    }}
]}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

But I am getting this error:

**"Invalid requests[0].updateSheetProperties: At least one field must be listed in 'fields'. (Use '*' to indicate all fields.)"**

If I add this:

```
body = {'requests': [
    {'updateSheetProperties': {
        'properties': {
            'sheetId': sheetId,
            'index': 1
        },
        "fields": "*"
    }}
]}
```

I get:

**"Invalid requests[0].updateSheetProperties: The sheet name cannot be empty."**

I even tried with my sheet name:

```
"fields": "2019-08-09"
```

But I get:

**"Invalid requests[0].updateSheetProperties: Invalid field: 2019-08-09"**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to move a sheet using gspread with Python.

  - You want to use `batch_update` of gspread.
- You have already been able to put and get values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, `body` was modified.

From:

```
body = {'requests': [
    {'updateSheetProperties': {
        'properties': {
            'sheetId': sheetId,
            'index': 1
        }
    }}
]}
```

To:

```
body = {'requests': [
    {'updateSheetProperties': {
        'properties': {
            'sheetId': sheetId,
            'index': 1
        },
        'fields': 'index',
    }}
]}
```

- In your case, please use `index` to `fields`.

#### Note:

- When you want to move the sheet and rename the sheet name, simultaneously, please use the following request body.

  ```
  body = {'requests': [
      {'updateSheetProperties': {
          'properties': {
              'sheetId': sheetId,
              'index': 1,
              'title': 'updatedTitle'
          },
          'fields': 'index,title',
      }}
  ]}
  ```

#### Reference:

- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Google landed me here when I was trying to make this work in Java, so for those people: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565275/freeze-rows-and-set-styles-with-google-spreadsheet-api/74693377#74693377